# New tag name for Zoom/Rush poker?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to create a generic tag that covers this new format of poker without using the branding specifics of any one site, i.e. Pokerstars has "Zoom"; Full Tilt *had* "Rush" (if it ever comes back!).

I suggest this as the format can be used for all variants, e.g. no-limit, limit, omaha, etc. but it's distinct enough to warrant it's own strategy questions.

Some suggestions. Maybe:

- fast-change
- quick-change
- quick-seat
- re-seat
- shift-seat
- ...

A common name might already exist but I haven't seen it.

Comment: I created the tag "rush-poker" and have started the process for assigning the synonym "zoom-poker": http://poker.stackexchange.com/tags/rush-poker/synonyms

Comment: Some recent changes. Pokertracker has just implemented a change so that these types of table are collectively known as "Fast Fold Tables".

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best option is to use any label that sites come up with (and/or that we see in questions) and have them be synonyms. So "rush" and "zoom" currently. Then when another emerges, we use it too. And just have the synonym system handle the difference.

Inventing new terms won't help categorization, since most visitors will have no clue what "quick-seat" actually means.

Comment: True about the inventing of new terminology. A problem with that is when the question is about the concept and not the poker-site, as in that case which tag should be chosen is problematic. It may be difficult at first but I still see creating a new tag as best.

Comment: The beauty of tag synonyms is that it won't matter which one they choose.

Comment: I'm with Jeffrey on this one - when someone is asking a general question, they're still going to know about the idea through the game's name on an existing site.